# How to do sequential call to Firebase auth.createUser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a very huge list of user objects that I want to import into Google Firebase which is basically just a network call. I want to do it sequentially just to ensure that it doesn't hit maximum number of allowed open sockets. How to do that?

Here's my code for parallel calls.

```
userObjects.forEach(function(userObject, index){
    auth.createUser({
    'email': userObject.email,
    'emailVerified': userObject.emailVerified
})
.then(function(userRecord){
   console.log("Successfully created a user with email:", userRecord.emailInternal);
   successCount++;

})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error creating the user: ", error);
});
});
```

Comment: FYI: I've got the paid account, so 100 concurrent connections is not the issue. I get ECONNRESET which probably occurs when you cross system's allowed open socket count.

Comment: What value does `successCount` have when you get the error or how often does it work?